# How to do loop inside subreports in Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports

How to create a subreports inside of a single main report and this subreport should loop twice or thrice based on the data . I want to fill the data in my Java Spring Boot application only from the Java side. I able to create a PDF with just subreport displayed only once.

Example:
//Main report.jrxml
User No:u123

//sub reports.jrxml
Sub User Number: u123-01

| Item | Cost Price | Sell Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Orange | 90.00 | 50.00 |
| Banana | 10.00 | 9.00 |
| Apple | 100.00 | 90.00 |

//sub reports.jrxml
Sub User Number: u123-02

| Item | Cost Price | Sell Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cake | 9.00 | 5.00 |
| Milk | 10.00 | 9.00 |
| Chips | 10.00 | 8.00 |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3YnJ.png)​

I tried generating one pdf with one table data, couldn't find a way to loop the sub report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a method to cycle through subreports by passing data from Java as a JRBeanCollectionDataSource. In my primary report, I retrieve the data as follows:
`<field name="subreportDTOList" class="java.util.List"/>`.

This data is then passed to the subreport via the dataSourceExpression: `<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{subreportDTOList})]]></dataSourceExpression>`

In the subreport, I can directly access the values within my DTO. Since the DTO is a list, it automatically loops through the subreport as needed.